# How can I proceed with my defect detection algorithm?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I am an undergraduate student working with detecting defects on a surface of an object, in a given digital image using image processing technique. I am planning on using OpenCV library to get image processing functions. **Currently I am trying to decide on which defect detection algorithm to use**, in order to detect defects. This is one of my very first projects related to this field, so it will be appreciated if I can get some help related to this issue. The reference image with a defect (missing teeth in the gear), which I am currently working with is uploaded as a link below ("defective gear image").

[defective gear image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LjfC.jpg)

Comment: You say you are looking for defects on the surface of an object so presumably you are not looking for the missing teeth on the right side? Maybe you could provide a second, marked up image showing the actual defect you are looking for please?

Comment: I would: search for gears (big white objects), then find the orientation (the small black interior holes can help), then subtract/XOR a good gear (gear without defects). If you find too many defects, retry with 90 degree rotations.

Comment: Actually, the defect(missing teeth) is visible in both gears. One is on the gear on left side (at the bottom part of the gear) and one one is on the gear on the right side (at the right side of the gear)

Answer (score 0):

Get the convex hull of a gear (which is a polygon) and shrink is slightly so that it crosses the teeth. Make sure that the centroid of the gear is the fixed point.

Then sample the pixels along the hull, preferably using equidistant points (divide the perimeter by a multiple of the number of teeth). The unwrapped profile will be a dashed line, with missing dashes corresponding to missing teeth, and the problem is reduced to 1D.

[image]

You can also try a polar unwarping, making the outline straight, but you will need an accurate location of the center.

[image]